# How to stop <div>s from moving into each other with float defined?

Tags: css, html

Very straightforward CSS question that I haven't been able to find the answer to so far:

I'm trying to lay out a page with two div's side-by-side in one row (using float:left; and float:right;) and then one div below them. The problem is that if the top row (defined as a div itself) is so wide that the space between the two divs can accomodate the bottom div, the bottom div moves up into the top row creating the appearance of a single row of three divs. I don't know if that's clear or not, but here's the code:

```
<div id="top div" style="width:400px;">
<div style="float:left;"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="100px" height="200px" /></div>
<div style="float:right;"><img src="images/ucbseal.jpg" width="100px" height="250px" /></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom div"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" /></div>
```

So, as above, since the top div has a 200px gap in between its left and right child elements, the image in the bottom div slides up between them. If I make the top div's width 399px that doesn't happen. I tried using the CSS "clear" property but that didn't solve the problem. I've always just worked my way around this seemingly-odd behavior in a sloppy way but want to find a better practice.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `overflow:auto` on the first div

```
<div id="top div" style="width:400px;overflow:auto;">
<div style="float:left;"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="100px" height="200px" /></div>
<div style="float:right;"><img src="images/ucbseal.jpg" width="100px" height="250px" /></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom div"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" /></div>
```

it will cause the container div to expand to the contents of its children and so the following div will maintain its location..

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot. Seems like this should be the default behavior since I closed the top div, but I'm sure there's a good reason. Thanks!

Comment: The default, as w3 states, is `visible` and that is why it is not working .. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow

Answer (score 4):

Try the 'clear' attribute on a new div:

```
<div id="top_div" style="width:400px;"> 
<div style="float:left;"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="100px" height="200px" /></div> 
<div style="float:right;"><img src="images/ucbseal.jpg" width="100px" height="250px" /></div> 
<div style="clear: both;" />
</div> 

<div id="bottom_div"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" /></div>
```

Comment: or just add a `style="clear: both"` attribute to the bottom div.

Comment: this worked great for me, i just added the clear style to the bottom div like Rimas suggested!

Comment: Hm, I just took another look at this. David Radcliffe's answer is actually better, so I changed my answer accordingly. Make sure you understand the difference between these. If you do as Rimas suggested, any padding on the "top_div" will be ignored because it collapses. If you add a clear div in that container, the container padding will have the (proably expected effect).

Answer (score 2):

I would add a div to clear the floats:

```
<div id="top div" style="width:400px;">
<div style="float:left;"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="100px" height="200px" /></div>
<div style="float:right;"><img src="images/ucbseal.jpg" width="100px" height="250px" /></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom div"><img src="images/xlab.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the suggestions above concerning **style="clear:both;"** are spot on.  However, I might try adding that style to your existing "bottom row" div.  It might save you adding a new div.

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not late but I was having the same problem and just figured this out. Has to do with the bottom Div. Set height and width to 100% for the bottom div and set overflow auto on the bottom div as well. Now the div will not move up to fill space.